# Mantener texto en texbox al recargar una pagina usando PHP

Tags: php, textbox

Tengo una pagina HTML la cual parcialmente se construye con PHP. 
El asunto es que tengo un formulario donde usando HTML tengo un textbox donde con el metodo `onchange="this.form.submit()"`  donde se anota un numero de identificacion. Con un codigo php, al enviar este textbox y si la longitud de su contenido es mayor que `0`, aparece un segundo textbox donde el usuario debe registrar un nombre y a su vez, con el metodo `onchange="this.form.submit()"`, al enviarse aparece un tercer textbox donde se anota el apellido de la persona.
Obviamente cada vez que se recarga la pagina cada textbox conserva su contenido.
El problema está en que en el caso del segundo textbox, donde se debe anotar el nombre de la persona, si por ejemplo, se coloca `"Juan Jose"` al recargarse solo aparece `"Juan"`. Yo quiero que aparezca "Juan Jose", es decir todas las palabras. El codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
    <b>CI:</b> <input  type="text" name="cedula" id="cedula" onchange="this.form.submit()" onblur="copiar()" value="<?php  $cedul = isset($_POST['cedula']) ? $_POST['cedula'] : null ; echo $cedul;?>"/>
  <?php
  $cedul = isset($_POST['cedula']) ? $_POST['cedula'] : null ;
    if (strlen($cedul)>0) { 
      $nombr = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : null ;
      echo "<b>Nombre:</b> <input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre'  onchange='this.form.submit()' value=$nombr ></>";
   }

   $nombr = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : null ;
   $apellid = isset($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : null ;

   if (strlen($nombr)>0) { 
     echo "<b>Apellido:</b> <input type='text' name='apellido' id='nombre' id='apellido' onchange='this.form.submit()' value= $apellid> </>";
   }
```

...
   Cualquier ayuda se agradece. Saludos.

Comment: Tienes que usar un medio de almacenamiento temporal, como una variable de sesión, una cookie o utilizar el Storage del navegador (Con Javascript)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque tu logica es confusa, leyendo lo que necitas deberia ser asi, ya que uno depende de otro, entonces debe ser anidado, es decir en el primer caso, no exite el nombre, pero como llego la cedula ahora si existira, en el segundo caso como ya existe la cedula entonces cabe la posibilidad que el campo cedula lo manden vacio. por eso siempre debes validar primero que la cedula este llena tambien y asi suesivamente, espero haberme hecho entender y que entiendas.

el codigo seria asi:

```
   <b>CI:</b> <input  type="text" name="cedula" id="cedula" onchange="this.form.submit()" onblur="copiar()" value="<?php  $echo isset($_POST['cedula']) ? $_POST['cedula'] : null ; ?>"/>
          //notese que optimice un poco este ternario de aqui
  <?php
  // $cedul = isset($_POST['cedula']) ? $_POST['cedula'] : null ;
  if (isset($_POST['cedula']) && !empty($_POST['cedula'])) { 
    $nombr = $_POST['cedula'];
    echo "<b>Nombre:</b> <input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre'  onchange='this.form.submit()' value='$nombr'>";
                          //aqui faltaban las comillas
     // $nombr = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : null ;
      //con este validas si si llego y si no esta vacio
     if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['nombre'])) { 
       $apellid = $_POST['nombre'];
       echo "<b>Apellido:</b> <input type='text' name='apellido' id='apllido' id='apellido' onchange='this.form.submit()' value= '$apellid' >";
     }
  }
```

espero te sirva y me cuentas

Comment: La alternativa brindada por srJJ no me soluciona el problema. Al colocar, por ejemplo, Ana Maria, en el textbox "nombre" y recargar la pagina aparece "Ana". Creo que las opciones planteadas por Alberto Siurob apuntan mas a la direccion correcta. Intentaré esto y luego comento.

Comment: La solucion fue guardar el contenido del textbox "nombre" en una tabla temporal y luego al recargar la pagina cargar el textbox con la consulta a esa tabla. Lo mismo procede con el textbox "apellido". Gracias a todos por su aporte.

Comment: creo que no es lo mas apropiado, en su defecto, lo que deberias es usar variables de session, asi seria mas beneficioso, yo solo segui tu logica